# Mule ESB Community Edition 3.4 - prevent from deleting original file

Tags: ftp, mule

I managed to set up a Mule project to download a file from a FTP, and save it on a local disk. However after transferring the file, Mule keeps trying to delete the remote file on the FTP.
Is there a way to tell Mule not to delete the original file and just leave it as it is?

Here's my project XML:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <mule ...>

    <flow name="copy-remote-fileFlow1" doc:name="copy-remote-fileFlow1">
        <ftp:inbound-endpoint host="ftp.secureftp-test.com" port="21" path="subdir1" user="test" password="test" pollingFrequency="60000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP">
            <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="box.ico" />
        </ftp:inbound-endpoint>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="I:\test\" outputPattern="fromMule.ico" responseTimeout="10000"
 doc:name="File" />     </flow>

 </mule>
```

And in my case, I don't have the rights to delete the file so I get an exception:

```
ERROR 2013-05-24 17:35:47,286 [[copy-remote-file].connector.ftp.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Failed to delete file box.ico. Ftp error: 550
java.io.IOException: Failed to delete file box.ico. Ftp error: 550
    at org.mule.transport.ftp.FtpMessageReceiver.postProcess(FtpMessageReceiver.java:202)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.transport.ftp.EEFtpMessageReceiver.postProcess(EEFtpMessageReceiver.java:71)
    at org.mule.transport.ftp.FtpMessageReceiver$FtpWork.run(FtpMessageReceiver.java:316)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: So what you want is to keep polling the same file over FTP again and again?

Comment: Yes exactly, and copy it over my local disk (with a different name).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your only option consists in extending `org.mule.transport.ftp.FtpMessageReceiver` in order to override the `postProcess` method, which is the one that takes care of deleting the file on the FTP server.

To register your custom `FtpMessageReceiver` use the `service-overrides` configuration element on your FTP connector:

```
<ftp:connector name="nonDeletingFtpConnector">
    <service-overrides messageReceiver="com.amce.NonDeletingFtpMessageReceiver" />
</ftp:connector>
```

Comment: I feared that this was the only solution, because it is quite heavy for such a small feature. Thanks a lot for your help David.

Comment: @David Is it possible doing this in community edition?

Comment: @BalwantChauhan Yes, absolutely, Mule CE can be extended at will.

Comment: @BalwantChauhan Comments are not the place for asking questions. Create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Adding few things to what David already mentioned. The NonDeletingFtpMessageReceiver class constructor should look like this :

```
public NonDeletingFtpMessageReceiver(EEFtpConnector connector,
        Flow flowConstruct, DefaultInboundEndpoint endpoint,
        long frequency, String value1, String value2, long value3)
        throws CreateException {
    super(connector, flowConstruct, endpoint, frequency);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to set `streaming="true"` on the FTP connector which would disable the file deletion.